# Ekeland's standardness-property inheritable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

[Ekeland's inverse function theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0294144910000788) gives weak conditions under which a function $f:E\rightarrow F$ between two graded Fréchet-spaces is locally surjective. The theorem requires
the codomain $F$ to be *standard* in the following sense:

**Definition.** A graded Fréchet-space $(F,\Vert \cdot \Vert_k: k\in \mathbb{N})$ is called **standard**, if for every $x\in F$ there is an approximating sequence $F\ni x_n\rightarrow x$ and constants $C(x)>0$ and $c(n)>0$ such that
$$
\Vert x_n \Vert_k \le C(x) \cdot \Vert x\Vert_k\quad \text{ and} \quad \Vert x_n\Vert_k\le c(n)^k,\qquad (k,n\in\mathbb{N}).
$$

---

Ekeland's main example for a standard Fréchet-space is $C^\infty(\bar \Omega)$ (for a smooth, bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, graded by either $C^k(\bar \Omega)$ or $H^k(\Omega)$ semi-norms). Here $x_n=S_nx$ for an appropriate smoothing operator $S_n$. While this idea allows to prove standardness of some other function spaces, I wonder whether one can sometimes get away easier:

**Question.** Suppose $F$ is standard and $F_0\subset F$ is a closed linear subspace. Is $F_0$ also standard?

The obvious problem is that for $x\in F_0$ we only get an approximating sequence in $(x_n)\subset F$, which might not lie in $F_0$.

---

In some cases life is easier:

- In the special case that $F_0$ is the image of a projection operator $P:F\rightarrow F_0\subset F$ such that for all $y\in F$ we have $\Vert P y\Vert_k\lesssim_{k} \Vert y \Vert_k$, we can simply put $\tilde x_n =  P x_n \in F_0$ to get an approximation from within $F_0$. However, even in Banach spaces we do not always have such projections.
- If the domain $E$ has the Heine-Borel property, one get's away with non-standard $F$. This was proved [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11228-020-00536-2.pdf).

Comment: This does, of course, not answer your question, but my feeling is that a positive answer would be much too good to be true.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Well, that would at least justify any extra effort in proving that a certain (sub-)space is standard. Do you know of any reference where this property is discussed in more detail? I skimmed some papers that cite Ekeland, but none gave me any more insight in how people typically verify standardness (beyond the two remarks above).

Comment: By the way, the article of Ekeland you refer to has a very bad start: The very first claim that, if the topology of a Fréchet space is given by a sequence of norms (not only semi-norms) then it is an intersection of Banach spaces, is wrong. This is known since a long time and is quite relevant for a problem of Grothendieck about the bounded approximation property. Perhaps the simplest example is in an article of Dietmar Vogt from 2010 in the Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. Hopefully, this is the only mistake in Ekeland's article.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Where exactly is the fallacy in Ekeland's paper: Are the maps $i_k$ between the local Banach spaces not necessarily injective? Also, can you please elaborate on the connection with the bounded approximation property? (Are you suggesting that if $F$ is the intersection of Banach spaces, then it satisfies the BAP and hence Vogt's paper gives a counterexample? I don't wee why this would be true though.)

Comment: You're right. The maps $i_k$ need not be injective as Vogt's example (and others) show. The relation to the bounded approximation property goes back to Pelczynski. This is probably explained in Vogt's article (or in the references cited by Vogt.)

Comment: Aha, thanks! Just for the record: A Fréchet spaces called **countably normed** if its topology can be generated by a sequence of *norms* and if additionally the canonical inclusion maps $i_k$ are injective (p.168 in Dubinsky's *The structure of nuclear Fréchet-spaces*). Then Vogt's paper, together with reference [3], states: If $E$ admits a continuous norm, then: BAP $\Leftrightarrow$ $E$ countably normed.
So the point is: Ekeland's paper only considers countably normed Fréchet-spaces and Vogt's paper gives an example of a Fréchet-space which fails to satisfy this property.

Comment: The question is a bit inadequate for the following reason: The conditions (3) and especially (5) in Ekeland's results seem to be in such a way restrictive (hence not at all "weak") for the maps to be considered that it is questionable whether these results of Ekeland posses any nontrivial applications. In particular, they *do not* generalize Nash−Moser. The joint paper with Séré from about 2015 (see arXiv) seems more promising but there the spaces are more restricted sinse they need to allow smoothing operators.

Comment: @TaQ Is this *adversity* of Ekeland's version discussed somewhere in more detail?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I have added as an answer a short discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The *principle* for getting examples of nonapplicability of Ekeland's theorem is described by the following simple

**Example.** With $\mathbb I=[0,1]$ consider the Frechet space $E=F=C^\infty(\mathbb I)$ with the norms $\|x\|_k=\sup\{|{\rm D}^ix\,s|:s\in\mathbb I\text{ and }i\le k\,\}$. Taking $k_0=0$ consider the second order polynomian map $x\mapsto x+x^2$ defined for $\|x\|_0<\frac 14$. Then for $Lxv=\frac v{1+2x}$ Ekeland's condition (5) in his Theorem 3 on page 97 in the Ann. Inst. Henri Poincaré paper [AN 28 (2011) 91–105] requires that $\|\frac v{1+2x}\|_k=\|Lxv\|_k\le m'_k\|v\|_{k+d_2}$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ and all the appropriate $x$ and all $v$ in $E$. Taking $v:s\mapsto 1$ and $x:s\mapsto\frac 18\sin(2n\pi s)$ and $k=1$ we get $\frac 12n\pi=|{\rm D}(\frac 1{1+2x})0|\le m'_1\|v\|_{1+d_2}=m'_1$ which *does not* hold if we take $\frac 2\pi m'_1<m'_1\le n$.

The same idea with only more complicated computations can be applied to more general spaces and maps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. First you considered a fixed polynomial $x(s)=s+s^2$ (since you wrote $\|x\|_0=1/4$,it might rather be $s-s^2$?) and I first thought that the map $L:E\to E$ would be be $v\mapsto v/(1+2x)$, but then you plug in other functions $x$. What is the map $L:E\to E$, then? Do you claim that Nash-Moser applies to $L$ but Ekeland does not?

Comment: No, I consider the (polynomial) map $f:E\supseteq{\rm dom}\,f\to F=E$ given by $x\mapsto x+x^2$ for which I have not given the specific name "$f$". Here ${\rm dom}\,f$ is given by $\|x\|_0<\frac 14$ and $L:{\rm dom}\,f\to\mathcal L\,(F,E)$ is the family of (right) inverses for the derivative of $f$ occurring in Ekeland's theorem. It it rather "well-known" that this kind of maps (and even much more general ones) satisfy the Nash−Moser conditions. Does this clarify the state of matters?

Comment: Thank you for this clarification.